# How to put a TTL/expiration on an HSET

Tags: redis, hashset, ttl

An HSET is like so:

```
HSET myhash field1 "Hello"
```

is there a way to put an expiration/TTL on the "field1" key. It's trivial to put an expiration on myhash tmk, but I don't know how to put a TTL on key of a hash.

https://redis.io/commands/expire

Otherwise, I am stuck using:

```
SET field1 "Hello"
EXPIRE field1 10
```

and putting all my keys at the top-level instead of a hash :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/1042

Currently it's not possible.

Comment: super lame oh well :(

Comment: You could code an abstraction layer which uses beneath the workaround you described, single keys.

Comment: yeah, but retrieving all the matching keys is less performant (using `KEYS xyz:*` is linear tmk)

Comment: if the SCAN command is good, then add an answer with that pls